# Button click shows java.lang.null pointer exception in android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, nullpointerexception

I am trying to open an activity by pressing button activty contains 5 Edit-texts and  1 spinner 
when I press button it show unfortunately closing login.apk.

here is the code snippet of registartion .java

```
public class Registration extends Activity {
EditText name,password,email,dob,design,cpassword;
Button submit,cancel;
Spinner gender;
SQLiteDatabase db;
String Gen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    gender=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    dob=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    design=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    cpassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

    db=openOrCreateDatabase("MobWalletDB",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Male");
    list.add("Female");
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    gender.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            MODELUserData userGivenDataObject=new MODELUserData(name.getText().toString()
                                                               ,email.getText().toString(),Gen,dob.getText().toString(),design.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

            if(QUERYUserReg.registerUser(db, userGivenDataObject)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User Registered!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Registration.this,Login.class));

            }else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration Failure!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             

        }
    });

    gender.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int in,
                long lg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Gen=parent.getItemAtPosition(in).toString();
        }
    });

}
```

}

and the Logcat shows the following errors

```
05-29 07:22:48.331: E/AndroidRuntime(13236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main05-29 07:22:48.331:     
E/AndroidRuntime(13236): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.login/com.example.login.Registration}: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
...

05-29 07:22:48.331: E/AndroidRuntime(13236): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 07:22:48.331: E/AndroidRuntime(13236):    at com.example.login.Registration.onCreate(Registration.java:49)
05-29 07:22:48.331: E/AndroidRuntime(13236):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-29 07:22:48.331: E/AndroidRuntime(13236):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-29 07:22:48.331: E/AndroidRuntime(13236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-29 07:22:48.331: E/AndroidRuntime(13236):    ... 11 more
```

please tell me whats the error?
thanks in advance

Comment: post Registration.onCreate

Comment: Please post your code. The more information we have, the easier it is for us to find the problem.

Comment: where is line number 49 in  Registration.java ?

Comment: if you got your answer then plz show some respect to ppl who helped you, at least single thanks???

Answer (score 1):

I believe the crash is here:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

You are missing a:

```
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit); // Or whatever your ID is
```

You also need to initialise `cancel`.

Answer (score 0):

you never initialize `submit`. In Jave you can not declare and use an Object without create it (you should call the new operator upon it). Probably you missed the `findViewById` of `submit`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your submit and cancel buttons. You are writing onClickListener for a non-initialized variable

```
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_submit_button);
cancel= (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_cancel_button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button id not inintialized on the Registration Activity.but u used onclick listener on submit button.so initialized it first.hope ur problem may be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourID);
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, when answering questions, please try to explain why you have posted the code in your response.